# how can i update mongodb to use pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

i write this code to put this data into mongodb to use pymongo

```
db.collection.insert_one({'url':'www.google.com', 'cate':[['a'],['b'],['c']]})
```

after command, surely data structure will be like this in mongodb.

```
url : 'www.google.com',
cate : {
       ['a'],
       ['b'],
       ['c']
}
```

and if i want to make new data structure like this.
i feel like if i use `update_one`code, it can be achieved.
but, i don't know how i should write the code...
can you help me ?

```
url : 'www.google.com',
cate : {
       ['a'],
       ['b'],
       ['c'],
       ['new_data_1'],
       ['new_data_2'],
       ['new_data_3']

}
```

Comment: oh in pymongo i dont have to do that. haha:)

Comment: So the name of your collection in the db is “collection”?

Comment: @Oussama oh haha i solved this issue, key point is '$push'  !!! thx to help me :) have a good day!!!

Comment: Shouldn’t the payload in the original command be: ‘cate’:{ [‘a’], [‘b’], [‘c’] } note the {} as opposed to []

Comment: Okay great! You should answer below :-)

Comment: @Oussama thx to help me !! lol enjoy ur day